# Is there a way to create an Accept attribute to enforce Accept header check in ASP.NET Core Controller Action?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Just wondering if there is a way to enforce through an Attribute in ASP.NET Core to check if the HTTP header value belongs of the to a set given values (e.g. `application/json`, `application/xml`)

I know there is the `ProducesAttribute` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1 ):

`[Produces("application/json", "application/xml")]`

But it's more about the supported content types and not really about the Accept header analysis.

I would have expected something similar which would return a 406 HTTP code if the value of the Accept header is not:

```
[Accept("application/json", "application/xml")]
```

If there is not such attribute out of the box, how can I create one?

Comment: Take a look at this answerr https://stackoverflow.com/a/44289056

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such an attribute is unnecessary. The `Accept` header is simply a way for the client to specify a preference for a particular response type, and the client is free to ask for whatever it wants. It's on the server to determine how to actually respond, and if it doesn't support a particular content type, then it simply returns a `415 Unsupported Media Type` response. Otherwise, it will return the first content type it actually supports according to the order of the content types in the client's `Accept` header.

FWIW, it's important to understand that HTTP and the underlying IP protocols are intentionally designed to allow loose communication between client and server. The very terminology of a "request", implies this nature. The server cannot and should not force any behavior on the client and vice versa. All either can do is specify their preferences and then *negotiate* (another key term) a response for a particular request.

Long and short, you cannot stop a client from asking for things like a particular content-type. However, the server can respond that it does not support the given type if that's the case.

Comment: "It's on the server to determine how to actually respond, and if it doesn't support a particular content type, then it simply returns a 415 Unsupported Media Type response." That was my point to facilitate some actions and what Accept values can be processed so that when the action body is processed it's only with value among the ones accepted.

Comment: That's determined by the media types that have been added to the server and things like the Produces attribute. If you don't want a particular thing to be eligible as a response, then remove it.

Comment: I'd like to add that the declaration of accepted types is valuable when using frameworks like swagger/openapi

Answer (score 6):

You can use `[Consumes("application/json", "application/xml")]`.