# Implementing a custom routing attribute like HttpGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I'm doing a project where I want to use Attribute Routing as was introduced in Web API 2. Now I'm trying to understand how attributes like HttpGet can work, and how I can implement my own routing constraint. I want to be able to specify a Content-Types that an Action can handle. For example like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ContentType(new[] { "text/json" })]
public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

I have found where the http method attributes are [implemented](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/321327f84b2b22dcff2e9beb06a9a64236c5cced/src/Mvc/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Routing/HttpMethodAttribute.cs), and I have also found the [IRouteConstraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.routing.irouteconstraint?view=aspnetcore-2.1), which seems relevant.

However I don't understand where the actual "filtering" for e.g. GET requests is handled. I tried looking for the source code by searching on GitHub, but I was unable to find the right routing logic.

Comment: Have u tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44289056

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for, this can be closed as duplicate