# What is the ASP.Net Core analogue of Request.AcceptTypes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm probably not even asking the right question, as I know neither ASP.Net nor ASP.Net Core, but I've been tasked with porting some code over, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to adapt this logic. The goal, I think, is to check what MIME accept types the client supports, then add them to the current request's headers.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156625/asp-net-core-web-api-action-selection-based-on-accept-header help?

Comment: No, but I appreciate it all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set your Request's ContentType to one of the ContentTypes that the request specifies it accepts.

It'll be something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SomeWebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class SomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult SomeControllerMethod()
        {
            Response.ContentType = Request.AcceptTypes.FirstOrDefault() ?? "text/plain";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

The FirstOrDefault() call will return the first item in Request.AcceptTypes. If Request.AcceptTypes is an empty array, it will return null, the default value of string. If it is null, the ?? operator returns "text/plain" instead of null.

Comment: You're misinterpreting my question. `Request.AcceptTypes` doesn't seem to exist in ASP.Net Core, which is my problem. When I ask for its analogue, I mean what do I use in Core instead? An answer that involves using Request.AcceptTypes doesn't really help at all.

Comment: My bad, Totally missed that. One min.

Comment: @Roderick Looks like its in the request headers Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Accept", out var contentTypes);

Comment: That comment is the real answer. Thanks

Comment: @Roderick That looks quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44289056/34092 ?

Comment: I could edit the answer to be the comment, but that seems pointless. I can't select the comment as the answer, though.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Request.GetTypedHeaders().Accept` to get type-safe access to the accepts header values.

Example:

```
// check if the client accepts JSON
if (Request.GetTypedHeaders().Accept.Any(aValue => aValue.MediaType.Value == "application/json"))
{
    // return some JSON
    // note that the client can also accept types less expicitly, for example via patterns, like */*
}
```

The accepted answer is for .NET Framework.