# ASP.NET Core RESTful, same routes but different actions

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, routes

I try to have multiple routes with equal URLs like files/{fileId} but different return values.
I would like to distinguish the routes based on the MIME type. In one case I want the file details in JSON format and in the other the file itself.

```
/// <summary>
    /// get a file by its Id
    /// </summary>
    /// <response code="200">The file for download</response>
    /// <response code="404">File id was not found</response>
    [HttpGet("files/{fileId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile([FromRoute] int fileId)
    {
        var fileModel = await _boFileService.GetFileStreamAndFileName(fileId);
        return File(fileModel.Stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileModel.FileName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// get the details of a file by its Id
    /// </summary>
    /// <response code="200">The details for the file, like name, status and type</response>
    /// <response code="404">File id was not found</response>
    [HttpGet("files/{fileId}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<BoFileModel>> GetFileDetails([FromRoute] int fileId)
    {
        return await _boFileService.GetFileDetails(fileId);
    }
```

At the moment I got the following error:

*Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0*

Has anybody an idea? Is it possible to have equal routes?

Thank you

Comment: How should the server know wether to call GetFile or GetFileDetails? Both paths are exactly the same. You could change then second [HttpGet("files/{fileId}")] to [HttpGet("filedetails/{fileId}")]

Comment: Use route like this `[Route("GetFileDetails")]` it would work

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish his needs via MIME type? Call `GetFileDetails` for `application/json` and `GetFile` for `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: Is there any reason _why_ you would want equal routes? And what behavior do you expect from your clients?

Comment: I edited the question. if possible,, my idea is to distinguish based on the MIME-Type

Comment: The 'Accept' header is made to define what output format the client expects (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept) - but: It's made to deliver the same content in different formats (xml/json/...) In your case, it's not the same content (file content vs. file meta) and one could argue that different resources should have different resource identifiers (URIs). If you want the same URL, you could simply use the same action, check the 'Accept' header and call another function based on the value.

Comment: Btw. the standard flow in asp.net is, that you action returns "data", e.g. an object. Then the framework has "output formatters" to translate your data into the requested format based on "Accept" request header. The problem in your case: It's not the same content, so you cannot simply format it e.g. with custom output formatters. (docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET Core web api action selection based on Accept header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44156625/asp-net-core-web-api-action-selection-based-on-accept-header)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the [ConsumesAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.consumesattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to describe what content types maps to which controller action.